# @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) annotation makes extra queries

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, entity-relationship, many-to-one

I have two entities

The first:

```
@Entity
data class EntityA(
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var entityB: EntityB,
    ...
)
```

The second one:

```
@Entity
data class EntityB(
    ...
)
```

The EntityA has many-to-one relation with `FetchType.LAZY`, so I expect that during a query to get EntityA only the main entity will be fetched with id of EntityB.

But when I perform query `entityARepository.findById()` I get extra query for getting all information about EntityB.

```
select ... from entity_a ...
select ... from entity_b ...
```

What should I do to get rid of extra query for getting EntityB? What should I do with relation to get only one query for main entity?

I have seen similar questions but they have not helped me, also suggestion about adding `optional = false` property to annotation have not helped me